# Approximate a $L^2$ integrable function by elementary functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

For a function $f(x)$ given in advance, assume that $f\in L^{2}(0,T)$. Here T is a fixed constant. For any $\sigma=\{0=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_n=T\}$,
set $$f_{\sigma}:= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} f(t_{k-1})\mathbb{I}_{(t_{k-1}, t_k]}$$ and $|\sigma|:=\max_{1\le i\le n}|t_i-t_{i-1}|.$

So my question is how to prove that $$\vert\vert f_{\sigma}-f(x)\vert\vert_2\to 0$$ as $|\sigma|\to 0$. My attempt is as follows:

$$\vert\vert f_{\sigma}-f(x)\vert\vert^{2}_2= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\int_{(0,T)} (f(t_{k-1})-f(x))^{2}\mathbb{I}_{(t_{k-1}, t_k]}(x) dx.$$ It is obvious that the integral inside the summation tends to 0 by the averaged continuity of Lebesgue integral, i.e. $$\lim_{y\to 0}\vert\vert f(x+y)-f(x)\vert\vert_1 = 0$$ for any $f\in L(\mathbb{R})$. But the crucial point here is there is also a summation outside the integral which will vary as n approaches $\infty$. Intuitively it seems that when $\vert\sigma\vert\to 0$ the length of every small interval tends to $0$.

I don't know how to figure it out, can you help me? Thanks very much!

Comment: There is a slight problem. How do you define $f(t_k)$ when $f\in L^2$ ? The point values of $f$ are not well defined. Perhaps you should replace $f(t_k)$ by the average value of $f$ on the corresponding interval ?

Comment: By choosing the left point in each interval. So how to prove the above rigorously?

Comment: Here $f$ is defined on the whole interval $(0,T)$, so $f(t_{k-1})$ is defined.

Comment: Here $f$ is a fixed function, given in advance. So the value of $f$ at every point is given ahead.

Comment: If $f=0$, then $f(t_{k})=0$. If $f$ is another function, it always has the only value at points.

Comment: Your statement is not true: Take $f$ as the indicator function of $(0,T)\setminus\mathbb Q$ and consider a partition with rational points $t_k$.

Comment: What Ryszard is saying @solver is that functions equal almost everywhere are identified in $L^2$. In other words, what you have written is not well defined.

Comment: @Andrew Zhang
This is in the pointwise sense, not $L^{2}$.

Comment: @Jochen In your statement, the answer is still $0$ because the integrand becomes $1$ but the measure of the domain approaches $0$.